# How to deobfuscate Javascript?

Tags: javascript, deobfuscation

I need help deobfuscating some Javascript. I've been trying to decode it for hours but I've gotten nowhere.

```
function divulge() {
  eval(function (p, a, c, k, e, r) {
    e = function (c) {
      return (c < a ? '' : e(parseInt(c / a))) + ((c = c % a) > 35 ? String.fromCharCode(c + 29)  : c.toString(36))
    };
    if (!''.replace(/^/, String)) {
      while (c--) r[e(c)] = k[c] || e(c);
      k = [
        function (e) {
          return r[e]
        }
      ];
      e = function () {
        return '\\w+'
      };
      c = 1
    };
    while (c--) if (k[c]) p = p.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + e(c) + '\\b', 'g'), k[c]);
    return p
  }('19 k=["\\N\\U\\O\\V\\P\\F\\a\\W\\a\\Q\\a\\t\\a\\o\\a\\g\\a\\X\\a\\x\\a\\u\\a\\y\\a\\l\\a\\t\\a\\p\\a\\u\\a\\g\\a\\o\\a\\l\\a\\p\\a\\m\\a\\f\\a\\o\\a\\g\\a\\o\\a\\p\\a\\v\\a\\f\\a\\g\\a\\o\\a\\f\\a\\y\\a\\m\\a\\f\\a\\l\\a\\g\\a\\x\\a\\u\\a\\Y\\a\\f\\a\\m\\a\\g\\a\\o\\a\\p\\a\\v\\a\\f\\a\\g\\a\\n\\a\\m\\a\\Z\\a\\t\\a\\l\\a\\m\\a\\n\\a\\m\\a\\c\\a\\g\\a\\r\\a\\n\\a\\m\\a\\t\\a\\n\\a\\Z\\a\\z\\a\\f\\a\\g\\a\\1a\\a\\Q\\a\\p\\a\\o\\a\\f\\a\\g\\a\\u\\a\\n\\a\\v\\a\\f\\a\\g\\a\\1b\\a\\g\\a\\o\\a\\Q\\a\\n\\a\\z\\a\\z\\a\\g\\a\\u\\a\\p\\a\\l\\a\\g\\a\\m\\a\\f\\a\\r\\a\\f\\a\\n\\a\\z\\a\\1c\\F\\1d\\F\\a\\d\\a\\e\\a\\1e\\a\\d\\a\\h\\a\\G\\a\\d\\a\\h\\a\\G\\a\\d\\a\\h\\a\\H\\a\\d\\a\\i\\a\\10\\a\\d\\a\\s\\a\\A\\a\\d\\a\\s\\a\\A\\a\\d\\a\\h\\a\\i\\a\\d\\a\\e\\a\\w\\a\\d\\a\\e\\a\\h\\a\\d\\a\\e\\a\\B\\a\\d\\a\\e\\a\\w\\a\\d\\a\\e\\a\\B\\a\\d\\a\\s\\a\\B\\a\\d\\a\\e\\a\\i\\a\\d\\a\\e\\a\\11\\a\\d\\a\\e\\a\\12\\a\\d\\a\\h\\a\\i\\a\\d\\a\\e\\a\\i\\a\\d\\a\\h\\a\\i\\a\\d\\a\\e\\a\\i\\a\\d\\a\\s\\a\\B\\a\\d\\a\\e\\a\\A\\a\\d\\a\\h\\a\\s\\a\\d\\a\\e\\a\\h\\a\\d\\a\\s\\a\\A\\a\\d\\a\\h\\a\\i\\a\\d\\a\\e\\a\\C\\a\\d\\a\\e\\a\\i\\a\\d\\a\\h\\a\\s\\a\\d\\a\\e\\a\\C\\a\\d\\a\\h\\a\\G\\a\\d\\a\\h\\a\\i\\F\\R\\S\\1f\\13\\O\\P\\I\\R\\14\\S\\N\\U\\1g\\V\\1h\\13\\O\\P\\D\\R\\14\\S","\\b","\\w\\y\\v\\B\\C","\\b\\b\\c\\d\\h\\b\\c\\e\\f\\b\\c\\d\\I\\b\\c\\e\\i\\b\\c\\f\\h\\b\\c\\e\\e\\b\\c\\i\\e\\b\\c\\i\\d\\b\\c\\f\\D\\b\\c\\e\\d\\b\\c\\f\\12\\b\\c\\f\\11\\b\\c\\i\\g\\b\\c\\f\\m\\b\\c\\f\\H\\b\\c\\g\\f\\b\\c\\g\\h\\b\\1i\\I\\c\\d\\p\\f\\t\\b\\c\\f\\o\\b\\c\\f\\10\\b\\c\\e\\g\\b\\X\\n\\r\\b\\c\\i\\h\\b\\c\\f\\e\\b\\c\\f\\d\\b\\c\\i\\f\\b\\c\\e\\m\\b\\c\\e\\h\\b\\c\\h\\g\\b\\c\\f\\f\\b\\c\\f\\g\\b\\c\\i\\m\\b\\c\\i\\i\\b\\c\\g\\m\\b\\c\\d\\D\\b\\c\\e\\o\\b\\c\\e\\I\\b\\c\\g\\D\\b\\c\\e\\D\\b\\c\\g\\g\\b\\n\\v\\l\\r\\C\\b\\w\\l\\p\\r\\l\\C\\x\\w\\b\\W\\N\\l\\w\\p\\n\\y\\l","","\\t\\r\\x\\G\\H\\A\\n\\r\\H\\x\\u\\l","\\r\\l\\y\\v\\n\\p\\l","\\a\\Y\\1j","\\a\\s","\\z"];1k(J(K,L,j,E,q,T){q=J(j){M(j<L?k[4]:q(1l(j/L)))+((j=j%L)>1m?15[k[5]](j+1n):j.1o(1p))};16(!k[4][k[6]](/^/,15)){17(j--){T[q(j)]=E[j]||q(j)};E=[J(q){M T[q]}];q=J(){M k[7]};j=1};17(j--){16(E[j]){K=K[k[6]](1q 1r(k[8]+q(j)+k[8],k[9]),E[j])}};M K}(k[0],18,18,k[3][k[2]](k[1]),0,{}));', 62, 90, '||||||||||x5C|x7C|x78|x32|x33|x36|x34|x35|x37|_0xd4b0x3|_0x6159|x65|x39|x61|x38|x63|_0xd4b0x5|x72|x62|x66|x64|x6C|x73|x6F|x70|x67|x68|x69|x74|x31|_0xd4b0x4|x22|x6D|x43|x30|function|_0xd4b0x1|_0xd4b0x2|return|x6E|x6A|x5B|x6B|x5D|x3B|_0xd4b0x6|x20|x3D|x75|x76|x77|x71|x44|x45|x46|x28|x29|String|if|while|45|var|x79|x7A|x41|x2C|x42|x47|x48|x49|x5F|x2B|eval|parseInt|35|29|toString|36|new|RegExp'.split('|'), 0, {
  }))
}
```

I ran it in JSBeautifier and got

```
function divulge() {
    var _0x6159 = ["\x6E\x20\x6A\x3D\x5B\x22\x5C\x75\x5C\x6B\x5C\x66\x5C\x38\x5C\x34\x5C\x76\x5C\x6F\x5C\x64\x5C\x70\x5C\x65\x5C\x66\x5C\x63\x5C\x64\x5C\x34\x5C\x38\x5C\x65\x5C\x63\x5C\x39\x5C\x36\x5C\x38\x5C\x34\x5C\x38\x5C\x63\x5C\x6C\x5C\x36\x5C\x34\x5C\x38\x5C\x36\x5C\x70\x5C\x39\x5C\x36\x5C\x65\x5C\x34\x5C\x6F\x5C\x64\x5C\x77\x5C\x36\x5C\x39\x5C\x34\x5C\x38\x5C\x63\x5C\x6C\x5C\x36\x5C\x34\x5C\x61\x5C\x39\x5C\x71\x5C\x66\x5C\x65\x5C\x39\x5C\x61\x5C\x39\x5C\x78\x5C\x34\x5C\x72\x5C\x61\x5C\x39\x5C\x66\x5C\x61\x5C\x71\x5C\x67\x5C\x36\x5C\x34\x5C\x79\x5C\x6B\x5C\x63\x5C\x38\x5C\x36\x5C\x34\x5C\x64\x5C\x61\x5C\x6C\x5C\x36\x5C\x34\x5C\x7A\x5C\x34\x5C\x38\x5C\x6B\x5C\x61\x5C\x67\x5C\x67\x5C\x34\x5C\x64\x5C\x63\x5C\x65\x5C\x34\x5C\x39\x5C\x36\x5C\x72\x5C\x36\x5C\x61\x5C\x67\x5C\x41\x22\x2C\x22\x5C\x32\x5C\x33\x5C\x42\x5C\x32\x5C\x35\x5C\x6D\x5C\x32\x5C\x35\x5C\x6D\x5C\x32\x5C\x35\x5C\x43\x5C\x32\x5C\x37\x5C\x44\x5C\x32\x5C\x62\x5C\x68\x5C\x32\x5C\x62\x5C\x68\x5C\x32\x5C\x35\x5C\x37\x5C\x32\x5C\x33\x5C\x73\x5C\x32\x5C\x33\x5C\x35\x5C\x32\x5C\x33\x5C\x69\x5C\x32\x5C\x33\x5C\x73\x5C\x32\x5C\x33\x5C\x69\x5C\x32\x5C\x62\x5C\x69\x5C\x32\x5C\x33\x5C\x37\x5C\x32\x5C\x33\x5C\x45\x5C\x32\x5C\x33\x5C\x46\x5C\x32\x5C\x35\x5C\x37\x5C\x32\x5C\x33\x5C\x37\x5C\x32\x5C\x35\x5C\x37\x5C\x32\x5C\x33\x5C\x37\x5C\x32\x5C\x62\x5C\x69\x5C\x32\x5C\x33\x5C\x68\x5C\x32\x5C\x35\x5C\x62\x5C\x32\x5C\x33\x5C\x35\x5C\x32\x5C\x62\x5C\x68\x5C\x32\x5C\x35\x5C\x37\x5C\x32\x5C\x33\x5C\x74\x5C\x32\x5C\x33\x5C\x37\x5C\x32\x5C\x35\x5C\x62\x5C\x32\x5C\x33\x5C\x74\x5C\x32\x5C\x35\x5C\x6D\x5C\x32\x5C\x35\x5C\x37\x22\x5D\x3B\x47\x28\x6A\x5B\x30\x5D\x29\x3B\x6E\x20\x48\x3D\x49\x28\x6A\x5B\x31\x5D\x29\x3B", "\x7C", "\x73\x70\x6C\x69\x74", "\x7C\x7C\x78\x32\x35\x7C\x78\x33\x36\x7C\x78\x32\x30\x7C\x78\x33\x37\x7C\x78\x36\x35\x7C\x78\x33\x33\x7C\x78\x37\x33\x7C\x78\x37\x32\x7C\x78\x36\x31\x7C\x78\x33\x32\x7C\x78\x36\x46\x7C\x78\x36\x45\x7C\x78\x37\x34\x7C\x78\x36\x39\x7C\x78\x36\x43\x7C\x78\x34\x36\x7C\x78\x34\x35\x7C\x5F\x30\x78\x32\x63\x36\x66\x7C\x78\x36\x38\x7C\x78\x36\x44\x7C\x78\x33\x34\x7C\x76\x61\x72\x7C\x78\x37\x35\x7C\x78\x36\x33\x7C\x78\x36\x32\x7C\x78\x37\x36\x7C\x78\x33\x39\x7C\x78\x33\x35\x7C\x78\x35\x34\x7C\x78\x36\x36\x7C\x78\x36\x34\x7C\x78\x37\x39\x7C\x78\x37\x37\x7C\x78\x34\x39\x7C\x78\x32\x31\x7C\x78\x33\x38\x7C\x78\x33\x30\x7C\x78\x34\x31\x7C\x78\x33\x31\x7C\x78\x34\x34\x7C\x61\x6C\x65\x72\x74\x7C\x73\x65\x63\x72\x65\x74\x6F\x73\x7C\x75\x6E\x65\x73\x63\x61\x70\x65", "", "\x66\x72\x6F\x6D\x43\x68\x61\x72\x43\x6F\x64\x65", "\x72\x65\x70\x6C\x61\x63\x65", "\x5C\x77\x2B", "\x5C\x62", "\x67"];
    eval(function (_0xd4b0x1, _0xd4b0x2, _0xd4b0x3, _0xd4b0x4, _0xd4b0x5, _0xd4b0x6) {
        _0xd4b0x5 = function (_0xd4b0x3) {
            return (_0xd4b0x3 < _0xd4b0x2 ? _0x6159[4] : _0xd4b0x5(parseInt(_0xd4b0x3 / _0xd4b0x2))) + ((_0xd4b0x3 = _0xd4b0x3 % _0xd4b0x2) > 35 ? String[_0x6159[5]](_0xd4b0x3 + 29) : _0xd4b0x3.toString(36))
        };
        if (!_0x6159[4][_0x6159[6]](/^/, String)) {
            while (_0xd4b0x3--) {
                _0xd4b0x6[_0xd4b0x5(_0xd4b0x3)] = _0xd4b0x4[_0xd4b0x3] || _0xd4b0x5(_0xd4b0x3)
            };
            _0xd4b0x4 = [
                function (_0xd4b0x5) {
                    return _0xd4b0x6[_0xd4b0x5]
                }];
            _0xd4b0x5 = function () {
                return _0x6159[7]
            };
            _0xd4b0x3 = 1
        };
        while (_0xd4b0x3--) {
            if (_0xd4b0x4[_0xd4b0x3]) {
                _0xd4b0x1 = _0xd4b0x1[_0x6159[6]](new RegExp(_0x6159[8] + _0xd4b0x5(_0xd4b0x3) + _0x6159[8], _0x6159[9]), _0xd4b0x4[_0xd4b0x3])
            }
        };
        return _0xd4b0x1
    }(_0x6159[0], 45, 45, _0x6159[3][_0x6159[2]](_0x6159[1]), 0, {}));
}
```

I'm pretty lost at this point. Is the first code not obfuscated? I don't have much experience in programming, it's a part of a computer science challenge I've been trying to do. I also tried replacing function in line 1 with alert and it said there's a missing semicolon but I'm not sure where.

Comment: So... You're new to programming and pick a *deobfuscation challenge* to try?

Comment: Deobfuscation isn't an easy thing.  I would try doing something else.

Comment: Your first code is more _minified_ than _obfuscated_. If you want to play with it, I suggest you pick a very nice JS editor and rename each variable one by one (by hand, with understandable names).

Comment: I didn't pick it and the challenge wasn't specifically deobfuscation. The challenge has many stages with varying challenges. It started with deciphering, to ollydbg, to steganography, and here I am at this thing.

Comment: It doesn't matter. If you're not somewhat experienced, don't pick challenges for experienced developers. Just learn the language.

Comment: I don't get error of missing semicolon with your code. Replacing some things with `alert` will probably lead you somewhere (it did for me). And I don't understand where you actually have a problem.

Comment: So the message is `"http://signin.camscsc.org/secrets"` after 3 decodes...

Comment: @IngoBürk - I think the OP may be coming at this from a different field and this just happens to be code. This wasn't *explained* in the original question, you see, hence "omg y" responses...

Comment: @JaredFarrish Maybe. As you can see, I still answered the question. ;)

Comment: This site can solve this challenge more or less automatically: http://deobfuscatejavascript.com/. Just paste in the code and press deobfuscate twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick tutorial on deobfuscating it. I will not go into too much detail because this was a challenge *you* are supposed to solve afterall.

Take the original code and look at its structure. It basically is of the form

```
function divulge() {
    eval(function(...) { 
        /* nobody cares what happens here */

        // now this is interesting, because p will contain the string that eval() will execute!
        return p; 
    }(...));
}
```

It should be fairly obvious now how to learn *what* this code will execute rather than having it actually execute: `p` will get `eval`ed, so just intercept it. This will show that it's just more code (obviously).

So let's start over! Looking at the new code, after beautifying it, we will see that the structure is basically the same. So someone is trying to be sneaky by obfuscating the code several times. Too bad we already deobfuscated it once, so we just repeat the entire procedure.

After the second time, we get code of the structure

```
var _0x2c6f = ["..."];
alert(_0x2c6f[0]);
var secretos = unescape(_0x2c6f[1]);
```

This will alert the following text:

```
This function stores some secret under some arbitrary variable whose name I shall not reveal!
```

And finally, `secretos` contains a link. However, I will censor the link here for multiple reasons:

```
http://signin.**********.org/secrets
```